# How can a celery task accept a list of files as an argument?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Actually, I don't know how I could make the task have a list of files as an argument.

```py
files = {}
    for file in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
        files[file.name] = file.file.read()

my_celery_task.apply_async(
    kwargs={
        'files': files,
    }
)
```

This throws the below error:

> Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable.

I also tried to add these files to the constructor of a class, but it's still not good because the object cannot be serialized.

If I use `files[file.name] = file`, it throws:

> InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable

Or if I use `files[file.name] = file.file.read().decode('utf-8')` it throws:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

I actually have no idea how to solve it. I need that dictionary of the form like `name: content` as an argument given to the task.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the file contents to your celery task? What do you want to do with them in the task?

Comment: In the task I call about 3 already existing methods and I cannot change the logic because I would mess up everything.
In general, in those functions I create other objects of the django imageField type, I also need the names of the files, etc., etc. It's complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a binary file as argument to a celery task. You need to store it on the filesystem (or S3 or another storage) and then pass the path to the files as argument.